# setTimeout change speed during run

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to change the setTimeout speed while running the function.

I think im almost there, there is something still not work on my script. but i can't figure out what.

Can someone help me ?

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
        polyfill: false,
        onInit: function() {
        this.update();
    },
        onSlide: function(pos, value) {
        tempPosition = pos + this.grabX;
        position = (tempPosition <= this.handleWidth) ? this.handleWidth : (tempPosition >= this.maxHandleX) ? this.maxHandleX : tempPosition;
        //timer = setTimeout(counter, value);
        //clearTimeout(timer);
        //var speed = value;
        //clearTimeout(timer);
        var timer = 0;
        timer.length = 0;
        timer = setTimeout(counter, value);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timer;


        //alert(counter);
    }
    });

    var counter = function() {
    imagesArray[i].setOpacity(0.00);
    i++;
    if(i > 23){
        i = imagesArray.length - 23;
    }
    imagesArray[i].setOpacity(0.60);
    speed = parseInt(speed);
    setTimeout(counter, speed);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = speed;
    };

    counter();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll try and point out some problems with your code Inside the `onSlide` callback, you have:

```
var timer = 0;
timer.length = 0;
timer = setTimeout(counter, value);
clearTimeout(timer);
```

So, every time the slider is used, you initialize the local variable `timer` to 0. You never use this value so this is not meaningful. In fact, it would be enough to break your logic, but there are other problems too. Then, you try to set the `length` property of `timer` to 0. Surely this must cause a runtime error? Numbers have no `length` property. Then you assign `timer` the id that `setTimeout()` returns, which is all well, but then, you immediately clear the timeout, preventing the scheduled `counter()` invocation from ever being executed.

The `counter` function, on the other hand, calls itself using `setTimeout`, but the ID that is returned is not captured, meaning this scheduled invocation will execute regardless of what you do inside the onSlide callback.

Then I don't see where the `speed` variable is defined or set.

Basically, there are too many problems with your code to go through them all in the scope of an answer. A sound approach would probably look something like this:

```
var timer, speed; //Global, or at least in a scope shared by both the onSlide callback and the counter function

$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
  ...
  onSlide: function() {
    clearTimeout(timer); //Cancel the currently pending execution of counter();
    speed = ... //Read value from slider
    timer = clearTimeout(counter, speed);
  },
  ...
});

var counter = function() {
  ...
  timer = setTimeout(counter, speed);
  ...
};
```

It's worth noting that with this approach, as long as the slider is adjusted before the timeout has passed, counter() won't get to execute.